# jQuery Mobile: Dynamicly loading content (Forms) via PHP no styles not applying

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

- Problem: jQuery Mobile themes are not applying to newly inserted dynamic forms.
- Forms are being inserted into the `<div id="formSuccess">` without any issues.
- Forms are generated from a PHP script
- Project is using jquery.mobile-1.0b1 & jquery-1.6.4

  ```
      var jqxhr = $.post("getForm.php", { form: tempVar},     function(data) {$("#formSuccess").page();   
      $("#formSuccess").html(data);   
      //$("#formSuccess").page("refresh");
     // $("#formSuccess").html(data).appendTo( "#some_page").trigger( "create" );
  })
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you should update to jQuery Mobile 1.0.1: http://www.jquerymobile.com/download

To answer your question, you need to tell the jQuery Mobile framework that you have updated the DOM and you want it to initialize the new content. You can do that with `.trigger('create')`:

```
var jqxhr = $.post("getForm.php", { form: tempVar }, function(data) { 
    $("#formSuccess").html(data).trigger('create');
});
```

Notice I used `.trigger('create')` after I added the new HTML to the DOM.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/YTvhF/